# Adding a colour picker to a Field in an MS Access 2007 Table?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I'm hoping to add a Color Picker to a field in an Access database table, instead of having to type in numbers manually.

I've looked online for help but I keep coming back to sites explaining how to add events to buttons on **Forms** rather than tables.

Is it possible to add event handlers to add custom code on table fields? And if so.. how?

Cheers for any help :)

Comment: Why not use a datasheet? It looks like a table but has many of the functions that a form has.

Comment: I think my table might be a datasheet actually.. it has a "Datasheet View" option. Sorry - my knowledge of Access is almost non-existent. I still can't see how I can achieve what I want with a Datasheet though, if that's what this is..

Comment: Unless you chose to create a form - the form wizaed is easiest - you do not have a datasheet form. Once you have a datasheet form, you can add events, such as opening a pop-up that shows various colours.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess I have a table, in that case. I currently have a lot of pre-existing tables which an exporter parses.. I'm not sure using forms is an option for us. Maybe I'm stuck with hand editing colours as numbers :(

Comment: Is a Form essentially just a UI that drives the data in assosiated tables? If so (and Google seems to say it is) then if you add that as an answer, i'll mark it as the answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess you could see it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a datasheet? It looks like a table but has many of the functions of a form. You can create a form easily with the form wizard. Once you have a datasheet form, you can add events, such as opening a pop-up that shows various colours.